# Storing affiliate image inside my database

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

This is a basic code which I use to pull info from my affiliate product feed. I'm pulling, as you will see below, picture links...and store the urls into my databse. The problem is that I'm showing 20 products per page, and if the affiliate serves isn;'t working properly it slows donw my sites alot.

What i'd like to do is store the whole iamges somehow and hot the urls... I think that will improve my sites performance alot. Any ideeas?

```
$feed = 'my affiliate feed';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

foreach( $xml->productinfo as $productinfo )
{
    $pic0 = $productinfo->picture[0];
    $pic1 = $productinfo->picture[1];
    $pic2 = $productinfo->picture[2];

         mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$table." (pic0, pic1, pic2) VALUES ('$pic0', '$pic1', '$pic2')");   
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You might want to read about [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: images are better stored in the file system than in the DB, IMO

Comment: You are right, but I can;t for the current aplication. Need to do it like that :(

Comment: @Denis your reference to a cartoon hardly helps find his answer lol

Comment: @Lawrence: I realize, but it might prompt him to worry about images called `'); drop table users; --`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change pic0, pic1 and pic2 fields to BLOB type. (You might also want to store the MIME type with getimagesize() for use with header() when delivering the images.)

```
$feed = 'my affiliate feed';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

foreach( $xml->productinfo as $productinfo )
{
    for($i = 0; $i<=2; $i++) {
        $pic[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($productinfo->picture[$i]));
    }
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table (pic0, pic1, pic2) VALUES ('$pic[0]', '$pic[1]', '$pic[2]')");
}
```

I presume that you have an ID field in $table. Deliver images in a new PHP script like this:

```
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) die('No ID');
if (!isset($_GET['pic']) || !in_array($_GET['pic'], array(0, 1, 2)))
    $i='0';
else
    $i=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pic']);
$sql = sprintf( "SELECT pic$i FROM $table WHERE id=%s", mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row[0];
```

Comment: Ty very much, I hope I can get this to work, I can't seem to place picture values into my mysql

Comment: I can't seem to echo the image, it turns all my webpage into text, think it has something to do with the header

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry that the solution didn't work. There was a typo "%2" instead of "%s". I will rerun my solution on my demo PHP server.

Comment: @webmasters It still works for me. As I commented some minutes ago, there was the "%s" typo before. Have you tried viewing one of the images? If affiliatepic.php is your new script, for example, have you tried `affiliatepic.php?id=1&pic=0`?

Answer (score 0):

well you can also store it as base64
blobs make the website not faster, the more db requests you have the more slow is the website
if that are just a few images its ok and if you have a fast db server